# PHP regex - capturing content between two strings (multiple results)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

After spending over 2.5 hrs, can someone help with below?

I have html file in format like:

Example 1

```
[[section_abc]]
<div>
several lines of html ...
</div>
[[/section_abc]]
```

Example 1

```
[[section_opq]]
<div>
several lines of html ...
</div>
[[/section_opq]]
```

Below is desired output:
Example 1:
group1: `section_abc`
group2: content between `[[section_abc]]` and `[[/section_abc]]`

Example 2:
group1: `section_opq`
group2: content between `[[section_opq]]` and `[[/section_opq]]`

Here is my current test line:

```
preg_match_all("/(\[\[)([^}]+)(\]\])/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Comment: Where is your code? What is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no section nesting, have a try with

```
preg_match_all('~\[\[(\w+)]]((?>[^[]+|\[[^[])*)\[\[/\1]]~s', $str, $out)
```

- `\[\[(\w+)]]` [captures](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) one or more [word characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `[[` inside `]]`
- In between section-tags used `(?>[^[]+|\[[^[])*` rather than `.*?` for better performance but still allowing `a[b]c`. If you got nested stuff you can easily [make this pattern recursive](https://regex101.com/r/X8ZfzN/2).
- `\[\[/\1]]` ends the section with [what was captured](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) in first capturing group.

See [php demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/704616) or [regex demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/X8ZfzN/1)

Comment: Using a capture and a backref doesn't make sense if you use `(?>[^[]+|\[[^[])*`. In the second part of the alternation, you only ensure that an eventual opening square bracket isn't followed by an other opening square bracket *(  https://regex101.com/r/7zbI5i/1 )*, but since you use a backreference for the closing tag, you can do more: you can ensure that the opening square bracket isn't the start of the closing tag (or eventually the same tag nested). To do that you only need to write: `(?>[^[]+|\[(?!\[/?\1\b))*`, that can be improved to `[^[]*+(?:\[(?!\[/?\1\b)[^[]*)*+` *(unrolled pattern)*

Comment: Thank you for your input @CasimiretHippolyte. Actually was about to post something similar to your recommendation but then thought it is probably more than needed. The first pattern is not for nested sections but allows something like `a[b]c` (included the [recursive version](https://regex101.com/r/X8ZfzN/2) however, [that would also work for such case](https://www.regex101.com/r/T4WTlx/1)). Both patterns were meant to match the full section (until `[[/section_abc]]`) as I don't know how this will be used later. +1 for your comment. Feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
(\[\[[^\]]+\]\])([^\[]+)(\[\[[^\]]+\]\])
```

Group 1 will contain openning tag
Group 2 will contain the data block
Group 3 will contain closing tag

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

`/(?<=\[\[(section_\w{3})\]\])(.+)(?>\[\[\/\1\]\])/s`

### Breaking down the regex

1. `(?<=\[\[(section_\w{3})\]\])` provides lookbehind for matching the strings starting with `[[section_foo]]` without including the tag
2. `(.+)` captures everything inside the tags
3. `(?>\[\[\/\1\]\])` provides lookahead matching the strings ending with the same `[[/section_foo]]` tag without including the tag (Note: `\1` is a reference to the first captured group, which is the tagname)
4. `/s` makes dot `.` match newline (and note that in the current regex newline symbols after opening and before closing tags are included in the match)

### Results

**Example 1:**

Group 1: `section_abc`

Group 2:

```
<div>
several lines of html ...
</div>
```

**Example 2:**

Group 1: `section_opq`

Group 2:

```
<div>
several lines of html ...
</div>
```

Comment: That is very close. Section naming is not really always section_ followed by 3 characters. It could be section_something or employee_data etc. Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possible this pattern could work (minimal):

```
\[{2}([^\W]+)\]{2}\n([^[]+)
```

**Result**:

*Match 1*

<sub>Group 1:</sub>

```
section_abc
```

<sub>Group 2:</sub>

```
<div>
several lines of html ...
<more><a href=""></a>
</div>`
```

*Match 2*

<sub>Group 1:</sub>

```
section_opq
```

<sub>Group 2:</sub>

```
<div>
several lines of html ...
<more><a href=""></a>
</div>
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/lCX9FA/1

Comment: This one is definitely neater.